# difference between $("#id").prop("hidden", false); and $("#id").show();

Tags: javascript, jquery

what is the difference between `$("#id").prop("hidden", false);` and `$("#id").show();` ?

I have tried both on a hidden `div`. but only`$("#id").prop("hidden", false);` works.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C# or ASP.NET so I've removed those tags.

Comment: Use $("#id").show(); to display the div..

Comment: Stick with what works, setting properties has been supported since the dawn of HTML. Hidden is nothing new; I can't say I've ever used the hide() and only saying that cause JQuery is a mess! :D

Comment: Do you mean `prop("hidden", true)`? I don't think setting hidden to false will do anything

Comment: @evolutionxbox $("#id").show(); was what i originally meant

Answer (score 2):

From the [jQuery hide() docs](https://api.jquery.com/hide/):

> This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" ), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. If an element has a display value of inline and is hidden then shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

[hidden property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden):

> The hidden global attribute is a Boolean attribute indicating that the element is not yet, or is no longer, relevant. For example, it can be used to hide elements of the page that can't be used until the login process has been completed. Browsers won't render elements with the hidden attribute set.

So in short, roughly, the difference is that jQuery hide sets the `display` style property of elements so that they are not rendered while the hidden property is more functional/ semantical - but can also be overwritten by css.

Use jQuery css manipulation functions (hide/ show) if your task is to style or animate something.

Edit: In your question you actually use `$("#id").prop("hidden", false);` which removes, if present, a hidden property from an element (which must not come from css). So if your element is actually hidden via css and you remove the hidden property it might stay hidden due to css.

If you want to show a hidden element use `.show()` or set `display` property via css.

Comment: checked with $(“#id”).show() as well..but that also won't make the div visible....only $("#id").prop("hidden", false); this does the job. and i couldn't figure out why !!  (initially it was hidden and i want to make it visible)

Comment: @NabeelMhd without seeing more code I cant help. What kind of element are you trying to show? Is it somehow hidden via CSS? How was it hidden in the first place?

Comment: i hid the div using 'hidden' attribute in div (ie, <div hidden>)

Comment: I cannot reprocude your issue. If an element has the `hidden` property and I use jQuery's `.show()` on it, it becomes visible. The hidden property stays but due to CSS it becomes visible. Please make a fiddle or codepen to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

$("#id").prop("hidden", false);
This modifies the "hidden" property of the html tag.

While $(“#id”).hide(); is similar to the css implementation "display: none".

Since you tried applying both to a hidden element i.e one which already had "hidden" tag in it. Only removing the hidden tag will make the element visible.

$(“#id”).hide(); wont remove the hidden tag and hence even though the display CSS would have changed, due to the presence of "hidden" property, it will not become visible.

use $(“#id”).show() to override the "hidden" prop and show the html element.

Comment: checked with $(“#id”).show() as well..but that also won't make the div visible....only $("#id").prop("hidden", false); this does the job. and i couldn't figure out why !!

Comment: @NabeelMhd The hidden attribute is very different to the CSS property `display: none;`

Comment: @NabeelMhd, Did you make this div hidden using $(“#id”).hide(); in the first place? If not then show() wont make much difference. Like I said $("#id").prop("hidden", false); deals with property tag and $(“#id”).hide(); deals with CSS styling approach. So entirely different things.

Comment: @rainGazer i hid the div using 'hidden' attribute in div  (ie, <div hidden>)